# Get position of finger(s) on the trackpad - from background process

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, applescript, trackpad

Using a background process, is it possible to get the position of the finger(s) on the trackpad in a Macbook -- irrespective of active application?

I am open to using Swift or Objective-C or applescript or anything else.

EDIT:
The intent is go do something like this: if there are two fingers - thumbs in this case - touching the trackpad, I want the J,K,L,F keys to move the cursor directionally like in vim, and other similar use cases.

Comment: Are you talking about a background process? Is the plan that it is checking at an interval or something like that?

Comment: Yes, it will most likely run as a background process. I don't need the finger positions constantly or even at regular intervals - I want to probe them at specific points, for example in response to some event.